# intro- vs. intra-

Tags: etymology, prefixes

I recently found out that “extrovert” is a misspelling and that it’s actually written *extravert*. That makes sense, because other words use the same prefix, e.g. *extraordinary*, *extradite*, etc., but nothing I can think of begins with *extro-*<sup>(1)</sup>.

However, *intro-* and *intra-* seem to be two different prefixes. There is *introduce* and *introspect* on the one hand, and *intravenous* and the more recent neologism *intranet* on the other hand.

What is the difference between *intro-* and *intra-* and what are their origins?

(<sup>(1)</sup> Even the end-credit section of a movie, the opposite of the *intro*, isn’t called an *extro* :) )

Comment: [Extrovert](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extrovert) [intro-](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/intro-) [intra-](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/intra-)

Comment: Hm, interesting. The close vote reasoning says “This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information.” — Such questions are explicitly welcome on StackOverflow. I wonder why English Language & Usage is different.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#link-where-can-i-find-answers-to-simple-and-basic-questions

Comment: The more interesting question to me is: If intra is the opposite to extra, what is the opposite to intro? Or in different words: intra means inside, extra means outside, intro means into. So which word mean out? Outro? Why not extro?

Comment: Actually the couple of dictionaries I checked listed "extrovert" as the primary entry and "extravert" as an alternate spelling. The ever popular Google ngrams shows extrovert as far more common. http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=extrovert%2Cextravert&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prefix *extro-* means ‘outwards’. The Oxford English Dictionary has entries for both *extrovert* and *extravert*, with no difference in meaning. The only other word in the OED beginning with *extro-* is ‘extrospective’. Its  Latin origin is the preposition *extra* which means ‘outside’. The ‘o’ appears to have replaced the ‘a’ of ‘extra’ by analogy with the Latin adverb *intro*.

*Intro* itself means ‘inwards’, ‘to the inside’, and is used in that sense as a prefix in English verbs and adjectives. *Intra* is a Latin preposition meaning ‘inside’ and is the origin of the prefix in English adjectives, typically those found in biological contexts.

Comment: Well, the examples of "intra-" words that come to my mind refer to things within some group or entity as oppopsed to between entities, like "intramural", "intradepartmental", "intragalactic", etc.

Comment: @Jay: But there are also ‘intraacinous’, ‘intraamniotic’, ‘intrarticular’ and ‘intracardial’, to name but a few.

Comment: *Intra nos*, this isn't a full answer.

Comment: @TimLymington: I do me best, guv.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I wasn't disputing that there are technical biological terms beginning "intra-". I was just trying to point out that your answer gave the impression -- intended or not -- that this prefix is primarily confined to such terms, when in fact there are at least a fair number of words used in more common speach. (As a percentage of total such words, the biological terms may be a large majority. If that's what you meant, no dispute.)